# What is the difference between cybersecurity and information security?

Tags: network, data-leakage, terminology, countermeasure, cyber-warfare

I'm trying to differenciate between those two themes : cybersecurity vs information security.

Broadly speaking I'd say cybersec is about network security (TCP/IP, router, firewall,...) and infosec is about data security (data exfiltration, wikileaks like, ...). But I'm not from a security background so I can't be sure.

Also, what would be the difference between the activies of an hacker threatening cybersec VS an hacker threatening infosec. Hence what are some of the counter-measure and deterrence means in use in those two fields (cybersec and infosec)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50687/discussion-on-question-by-jason-krs-what-is-the-difference-between-cybersecurity).

Answer (score 5):

**Information security** is data-centric, meaning about safeguarding data for the purpose of preventing unauthorized access, use, disclosure, disruption, modification, inspection, recording or destruction of information.  Information security is agnostic to the form the data takes (electronic, or paper).

**Cybersecurity** is about safeguarding information systems and the data they contain.  Cybersecurity is broader and includes 'Information Security' with respect to the protection of digital information.

Finally, cybersecurity is often modelled under 3 rubrics; security awareness; technology; and governance (or in different words, people, processes and technology)